# creates programmatically a taxonomy in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I am new to drupal, I need to create in my .install custom module file a taxonomy, and assign this taxonomy to a specific content type. Any idea how to do it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I assume that with "create a taxonomy" you mean "create a taxonomy vocabulary". If this is the case, you need to populate an array such as:

```
  $vocabulary = array(
      'name' => t('<VOCABULARY_NAME>'),
      'multiple' => 0, // or 1, if you need multiple terms associated to any single node
      'required' => 0,  // or 1, if the association is required
      'hierarchy' => 1, // or 0, if is a tag-like term
      'relations' => 0,
      'module' => '<YOUR_MODULE_NAME>',
      'weight' => 0,
      'nodes' => array('<YOUR_NODE_TYPE>' => 1),
    );
```

and save the vocabulary by issuing

** EDIT **

```
$ret = taxonomy_save_vocabulary($vocabulary);
```

If `$ret == 1` you have correctly saved your vocabulary and `$vocabulary['vid']` will have the vid of the newly created vocabulary. If you want to add terms to it, you create arrays:

```
$term = array(
  'vid' => <VOCABULARY_VID>,
  'name' => "<TERM NAME>",
  'description' => "An optional description for the term",
  'weight' => <AN_INTEGER_OPTIONAL_VALUE_FOR_WEIGHT>,
);
$ret = taxonomy_save_term($term);
```

and again $ret will be set to a status value of your save operation and $term['tid'] will be the term id of the new term.

Comment: Thank you ! do you have an idea how to populate the terms of this vocabulary ?